# is there any playground for brute force?

Tags: brute-force

Is there a site where i can make an account and run my brute forcer to check it for infinite attempts?

Something which does a HTTP request and no javascript submit.

Comment: a javascript submit does normally in the end still do a HTTP request

Comment: Brute-forcing a HTTP login form is quite close to a denial of service attack, because it consumes considerable network and computing resources. I don't think you will find someone allowing you to do this for free.

Comment: @Philipp Yes that's true. I realized I should do it locally only. And the irony is I have forgotten my router passwords and don't wish to reset, and go through the ordeal of registering MAC addresses. So probably will just develop a PHP page for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try on some deliberately insecure web applications like WebGoat running on your machine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get why he can't use WebGoat for the testing. Unauthorized brute force on some live site may put him in to trouble.
Apps like WebGoat is meant for testing. He can create own accounts and try to run his brute force tool on it.

Comment: @pavanw3b the problem isn't with WebGoat, but with the quality of the Answer. While we tend to prefer more complete Answers, this does in fact seem to Answer the question sufficiently. I'm allowing this.